# Add custom image watermark based on role and content type

Tags: 7, rules, media

I am adding small watermark logo to all images using [ImageCache Actions](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions)

There are 10 users that are publishers of their own galleries, and i want to protect their images (i know they can not be protected 100%, but its something at least, and it looks nice).
When creating profile, those users must choose main image (logo) which would be used as watermark.

All galleries for all users have same formating (same image style), lets say:
Scale and crop, 300x250, watermark 40x40 - center, alpha 50%.

Watermark for now is website logo, but since all users are publishers of their own content, it would be nice feature to automamticly use their own logo as watermark to the content they are author of.

I can not find logic in how to do this with available modules, but seems to me it could be implemented easy, since all parameters in image style remains the same except the watermark image for author of the node.

Anyone has a suggestion how to do this? Maybe using rules?

Comment: Can you provide some more details about that "add imageaction watermark"? Ie how you implemented that? Maybe any contributed modules related to it that you uses?

Comment: I updated the question with better explanation.